# Array created from JS Object shows circular object when logged in console

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, circular-reference

I am looking to create an array of object created from multiple inputs. Each time user press the `Add to Array` button it should add a new object to the array. However, when I log the array to console, it shows circular reference.

**My test code is as below:**

```js
var selected = [];

var name = $(".name").val();
var id = $(".id").val();
var data = $(".data").val();

var data = {
  name : $(".name").val(),
  id : $(".id").val(),
  data: $(".data").val()
}
$("button").click(function(){    
    selected.push(data);
    console.log(selected);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="name" value='Some name' />
<input type="text" class="data" value='some data' />
<input type="text" class="id" value='12' />
<p id="demo"></p>
<button>Add to array</button>
```

I want a normal array of all values I have added, for use later. I am not sure of is circular reference is what I should end up with.

Is this a wrong way to maintain collection of objects, which will be posted to the server later?

Comment: You're defining `data` only once, so every time the same object is added to the array. You should define `data` inside the click handler function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to declare the var data in the function on click like in the below example:

```js
var selected = [];

$("button").click(function() {
  var data = {
    name: $(".name").val(),
    id: $(".id").val(),
    data: $(".data").val()
  }
  selected.push(data);
  console.log(selected);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="name" value='Some name' />
<input type="text" class="data" value='some data' />
<input type="text" class="id" value='12' />
<p id="demo"></p>
<button>Add to array</button>
```